# Get the latest running process instance in Activiti

Tags: java, api, alfresco, activiti

Is it possible to get the latest running process in Activiti with 
createProcessInstanceQuery ?

runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processDefinitionKey('myKey').active().singleResult().getProcessInstanceId()
I want to get the process instance ID of that definition but only the latest running process.
Thank you

Comment: if you have got your answer by using community https://community.alfresco.com/thread/231155-getting-the-latest-running-process-instance so please close this question.

Answer (score 2):

To get a specific running process instance ID , you can use the HistoryService with :
for example to get the last started process instance with specific definition key:

```
historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().unfinished().processDefinitionKey("YOURKEY").orderByProcessInstanceStartTime().desc().listPage(0,1)[0].id
```